# Read a specific line from a file index

Tags: python, indexing

how can I read a specific line from a file?

`user.txt`:

```
root
admin
me
you
```

When I do

```
def load_user():
       file = open("user.txt", "r")
       nextuser_line = file.readline().strip()
       print(nextuser_line)
       file.close()
```

root will be printed, but I would like to read admin from the file. So I try to read the next line index using `[1]`

```
def load_user():
       file = open("user.txt", "r")
       nextuser_line = file.readline().strip()
       print(nextuser_line[1])
       file.close()
```

instead of printing `'admin'`, the output is `'o'` from `'root'`, but not the next line from the file.

what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to read a file line-by-line into a list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3277503/how-to-read-a-file-line-by-line-into-a-list)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`readline()` reads the first line. To access lines through index, use `readlines()`:

```
def load_user():
    file = open("user.txt", "r")
    lines = file.readlines()
    print(lines[1])
    file.close()
```

```
>>> load_user()
'admin'
```

To remove the `\n` from the lines, use:

```
lines = [x.strip() for x in file]
```